# Spelling Bee - real combinatorics example

Tags: combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

The hint section of a puzzle game indicates that are eighteen words starting with G.

The number of words having four, five, six or seven letters are 7,3,7 respectively 1.
There are 6, 1, 8 and 3 words starting with GE, GH, GI and GL

For example

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
7 & 3 & 7 & 1 \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 2 &   & GE & 6 \\ \hline
1 &   &   &  & GH & 1 \\ \hline
3 &   & 4 &  1 & GI & 8 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 &  & GL &3\\ \hline
\end{array}

satisfies the eight conditions.

How many non-negative solutions has this system of eight equations ?

I got 1274 solutions by Polya and I see no other way of doing this.

Are there other ideas ?

Comment: I voted to reopen because this question asks for the *count* of solutions, not just how to find one solution.

Comment: Yes indeed, without specifying a solution, I obtained the number of 12,978,645,843,602 matrices for the pointed similar problem, which is a linear algebra issue.

Comment: FWIW: This is a question about enumerating contingency tables with prescribed margin sums, and can be answered  easily by brute force computation using the code provided here.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621792/what-are-the-number-of-ways-of-distributing-n-objectsmixture-of-distinct-and-id/3624977#3624977

Comment: MathWonk thank you, you made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about enumerating the number of contingency tables that have prescribed margin sums. This is a topic of interest in statistical design that has inspired much research (by e.g Diaconis, Barvonik,  [deLoera](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Edeloera/contingency.html)) and can be tackled with rather sophisticated methods. The following is a sketch of an elementary (but cumbersome) approach whose execution would be straightforward but tedious. It's a divide and conquer strategy. *It does not use Polya's method.*

1. Consider first as an easier problem  any  2x2 contingency table (whose entries are 4 unknowns). Once its four margin sums (denoted $R_1, R_2, C_1, C_2$) are prescribed, you get 4 equations for the four unknown table entries. However, the margin sums are subject to a compatibility condition $R_1+R_2= C_1+C_2$ which  reduces the dimensionality of the linear system of constraints by 1. Thus the solution set of this linear system is one-dimensional, parametrized by e.g.  the (1,1) entry of the table, which we call $x$. The requirement that all four tabular entries be positive imposes four inequalities on $x$:  $ x\geq 0, x\leq C_1, x\leq R_1, x\geq R_1- C_2$. The solution set for $x$ is an interval whose endpoints are explicitly determined by these constraints. Obviously the number of solutions $Q$ is an explicit function of the input data $(R_1, R_2, C_1, C_2)$.
2. Consider now any  4x4 table whose unknown entries have  prescribed  margin sums. Draw and quarter the table: split the 4x4 table into  four disjoint 2x2  sub squares. The  vertical and horizontal bisectors form a cross.  Consider the margin sums of each of these small 2x2 sub-squares. (There are in all 4x4=16 such small sums).It suffices to know only 8 such small sums to determine all the other small sums. (Specifically it suffices to know all the small sums inside the upper left and lower right subsquares.) These 8 necessary small sums can be entered at locations on the cross.
   Now apply this process in reverse.  Imagine filling in the cross with every feasible collection of such 8 small entries. (Tabulating all those possible feasible choices is of course tedious! For example, the top entry in the cross could be any number between 0 and $R_1$).
   However,  once you have assigned values to all the  entries in the cross, you can then compute the number of ways to fill in the 2x2 sub squares using the equation in step (1). Because the internal contents of the sub-squares are independent of one another  (once the cross entries are prescribed) the number of ways you can create the big 4x4 tables is the product of the ways you fill in each of the four sub-squares. Now sum such products over all possible crosses.

Comment: In the 60's these issues were called "store and inventory" and they were related to Polya. Whatever the name, it is about writing a GF then extracting the desired coefficient.  The paper you pointed thus describes a store that contains four kinds of items, 592 in total, distributed in 4 shelves.  My PC slows down after 100 items.